# Probability that event $A$ occurs but event $B$ does not occur when events $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive

Tags: probability

Events $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive. Suppose event $A$ occurs with probability $0.74$ and event $B$ occurs with probability $0.22$.

1. Compute the probability that $A$ occurs but $B$ does not occur.
2. Compute the probability that either $A$ occurs without $B$ occurring or $A$ and $B$ both occur.

Answers:

1. $\Pr(A \cap \neg B) = \Pr(A) + \Pr(\neg B)- \Pr(A \cap B) = 0.74 + 0.78 -(0.74 \cdot 0.78)=0.9428$
2. $\Pr([B \cap A] \cup [A \cap B])= \Pr(\neg B \cap A) + \Pr(A \cap B) = 0.78 \cdot 0.74 + 0.74 \cdot 0.22=0.74$

Is it correct?

Comment: What is your *definition* of mutually exclusive events?

Comment: That means very different from each other?

Comment: That's not a mathematical definition. One definition is $P(A \cap B) = 0$.

Comment: ohhhh!!!!!!  so for no.1 it should be 0.74+0.78?

Comment: Can a probability be $>1$?

Comment: No..................

Comment: Can you please tell me the final answer for both 1 and 2, i will work out the steps

Comment: You cannot use $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ as the events are not independent.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing, as is usual ([e.g. here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusivity)) that mutually exclusive means that $P(A \cap B) = 0$ we have that $P(A \land \lnot B) = P(A \setminus B) = P(A) - P(A \cap B) = P(A) = 0.74$.

The final one is then just $P(A)$ too. $A$ cannot occur at the same time as $B$.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Mutually exclusive *implies* that $P(A\cap B)=0$ which is enough here. The actual meaning of it is that $A\cap B=\varnothing$.

Comment: @drhab Quite. And so both parts are just roundabout ways of asking for $P(A)$. A bit confusing for the OP maybe.